# add broad cast receiver to volume button android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, volume

I want to make  broadcastreceiver to volume button  in android.
when clicking up and down to in 3 seconds to  open my aapplication.

is it possible ? if yes i will be happy to get the broadcastcode for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no BroadcastReceiver for volume up or down button presently.
Alternate may be a service but it is not recommended to run a service all the time since that consumes both battery and memory.